# Battery with resistor: looking for verification that my understanding is correct

Tags: batteries, current, resistors, circuit-design

If I have a 12 V, 18 Ah battery, and I use a 4 Ω resistor, I will have 12 V and 3 A on the other side of the resistor, and I will have a current for about 6 hours - correct?

Comment: what is `other side of the resistor`? ... approx 3 A everywhere in the circuit, if the resistor is connected between the two battery terminals ... current flows through the resistor ... it does not start, or stop, at a resistor lead

Comment: Depends on battery. It might be that it has 18Ah, when discharged during time of 20h, so, if you discharge at higher rate during 6h only, you likely get much less than 18Ah. And do hope the battery is not 100% empty because many batteries get damaged at full discharge. So depends on battery.

Comment: Many battery chemistries (i.e. Lead Acid, alkaline..)  don't output a constant voltage for their entire discharge.    Some do (like NiMH and most lithium)  You need some fancier equipment than a simple resistor to really measure A-Hr.   Anyhow, also note that 12V and 3A in your resistor (yes your math is correct) would mean POWER = 12 * 3 = 36 watts.  THATS ALOT   You'll melt or blow up just about any resistor you have in your drawer.  Need a pretty big resistor to handle that power.

Comment: What one kind of 50W resistor looks like: https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Vishay%20Dale%20Photos/RH%20SERIES%2049.99x28.96mm.jpg

Comment: Rocket engineers preferred Silver  cadmium  batteries, also used in the 1st electric car 120 yrs ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are only connecting a resistor as the load, then yes. Kinda.

Basic ohms law determines the numbers you provided. V=IR but we are looking for I amperage in Amps, so I = V/R, I = 12V / 4 Ohms = 3 Amps. And then for runtime, you take capacity in Amp Hours and divide by Amps. 18 Ah / 3 A = 6 Hours.

Then reality hits. Batteries aren't ideal. They have a nominal voltage (12V) but in reality that voltage can be from 14 to 9.5V. Capacity is estimated at 18 Ah when you follow the tested scenarios per the datasheet, but it will vary base on current drawn, temperature, age, initial starting voltage. Resistance of the wires can change everything. Wires are just resistors in a different shape. Too small of wire size or dirty cables and your 4 Ohm load now became 6 Ohms. And remember when I said voltage will vary? Well since the voltage varies, but the load stays the same? Current drawn will have to change in proportion and the runtime will be different. At 14 Volts your 4 ohm load will now draw 3.5 Amps but at 10 Volts it will be 2.5 Amps. And then there is internal voltage drop and bounce back.

Look at this graph from a random 12 V 18 Ah agm battery. https://www.oraclebattery.com/Portals/0/adam/OracleProductGallery/7sHP_c7bo0-bnZD_bzp3kA/Specifications/Oracle%20spec-FS12180.pdf

[image]

Only at 0.05C or 0.9 Amps (1C being roughly 18 Amps here) do you get close to 20 hours usable runtime. While 0.2 C or 3.6 Amps draw will only get you 4 hours. Not 6. It's just not linear. While 0.1C or 1.8 Amps only gets you 9 hours, not 10 like the math would suggest. In ***ideal*** situations.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually it seems like you are correct except you are saying "the other side of the resistor" which is unclear.

Also you say "use a 4 Ohm resistor." But it is not clear HOW you are using it.

So I am going to draw a schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhsCiY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see from AM1 and AM2, the current is 3 Amps both before and after the resistor. The voltage across the resistor is 12 V. The battery, if it is 18 Ah, will last (conceptually) 6 hours. We are ignoring a lot of real world issues here, but this is the "nice" version. Sort of like in physics when you ignore friction.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the discharge characteristics of a [typical 12 V 18 AH lead acid battery](https://contrel.com/media/pdf/0b/a6/5e/6_CNFJ-185714a7019c8b7.pdf).

[image: constant current discharge characteristics, 12 V, 18 Ah battery]

Comment: This is due to the Peukert Effect, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law, which results in a battery rated 20 A-h over a 20 hour period (1/20 C) will exhibit only half that capacity at 20A (1C). I have an on-line Peukert calculator: http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm

Comment: Thank you, Paul, that's useful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, roughly.  But you're not accounting for internal resistance of the battery.  Look up the specs of your battery online and add its internal resistance to your 4 ohm resistor; then redo your math.  But your understanding is correct.

Further understanding: amp-hour is a charge.  Amp = Charge per time.  Hour = time.  Once your battery is drained of its charge, it will have no more juice.

Also, there are other factors, like decay effects as charge is lost, and temperature dependent factors, but those are not significant for a broader understanding.